# navigation bar doesn't show inside popup

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3

I'm using the `PopupDialog` library and have a button inside it. when user click on this button, I want to open a view controller that has a navigation bar.

my function inside `PopupDialog` controller :

```
func cliclOnContent(tapGestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer)
{

    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ContentAJobViewController") as! ContentAJobViewController
    controller.job_id = self.gh.id
    self.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

but when my controller shows view (`ContentAJobViewController`), my navigation bar is hide:

[image]

my library link:
https://github.com/Orderella/PopupDialog

Comment: Do you want your current Navigation Bar to still be active? Or do you want a new Navigation Bar in your "popup" view?

Comment: I want to use current navigation of fist controller that show my popup. `A=>popup=>B`. I want to use `A` navigation.

Comment: OK - well, the `PopupDialog` library looks like it is designed for presenting modal views, which means the view will not be part of your Navigation Controller - and will be covering the bar. You *could* dig into that library and use the animation styles for adding a subview... or look into customizing the transitions used by the Navigation Controller.

Comment: I think I must close this popup and show`B` controller.

Comment: I'm assuming you are using the `PopupDialog` library because you like the transition effects? It's pretty simple to add in code so you would `A=>Popup` and then when you close the popup automatically do `A=>B` (with or without the "slide in" animation).

Answer (score -1):

in order to keep the current navigation controller you must use `self.show(controller, sender: self)`. But I don't understand where you are using the PopupDialog in this case.